# Traverse a NodeList from querySelectorAll with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, selectors-api

I want to traverse a NodeList coming from querySelectorAll.

**not working**

```
var nodelist = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('tr.firstrow');
});

this.echo("nodelist.length=" + nodelist.length);

for (var i=0; i<nodelist.length; i++) {
    this.echo("i=" + i);
    line = nodelist[i];
    this.echo("Line: " + line.innerText);
}
```

What I get is this:

```
nodelist.length=3
i=0
this it the first line 
i=1
```

After the i=1, the output freeze. For the first item the "for" cycle runs as expected, but then it does not continue. When I run the querySelectorAll in the browser console, I see all three different items.

And here I found out a method that works:

**works**

```
var nodelist = this.evaluate(function() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('tr.firstrow');
    var array = [nodes[0].innerText,nodes[1].innerText,nodes[2].innerText];
    return array;
});
this.echo("nodelist.length=" + nodelist.length);
for (var i=0; i<nodelist.length; i++) {
    this.echo("i=" + i);
    line = nodelist[i];
    this.echo("Line: " + line);
}
```

But this is inconvenient.

Then I tried to convert this nodelist into an array. But this approach was also not working, because the return value from the evaluate function was lost.

**not working**

```
var nodelist=this.evaluate(function() 
{
console.log("...evaluate()");
var fr_n=document.querySelectorAll('tr.firstrow');
console.log("fr_n.length:" + fr_n.length);

var fr_a=Array.prototype.slice.call(fr_n);

console.log("fr_a.length:" + fr_a.length);
console.log("typeof fr_a:" + typeof fr_a);
console.log("fr_a[0]=" + fr_a[0].innerText);
console.log("fr_a[1]=" + fr_a[1].innerText);
console.log("fr_a[2]=" + fr_a[2].innerText);

return fr_a;

});

this.echo("nodelist.length=" + nodelist.length);

if (Array.isArray(nodelist))
{
 this.echo ("nodelist is array");
}
else
{
 this.echo ("nodelist is not array");
}

for (var i=0; i<nodelist.length; i++)
{
 this.echo("i:" + i);
 line = nodelist[i];
 this.echo("Line: " + line); 
};
```

Produces the following output:

```
remote console.log: ...evaluate()
remote console.log: fr_n.length:3
remote console.log: fr_a.length:3
remote console.log: typeof fr_a:object
remote console.log: fr_a[0]=This is the first line I want to see 
remote console.log: fr_a[1]=This is the second line I want to see
remote console.log: fr_a[1]=This is the third line I want to see
nodelist.length=0
nodelist is array
[info] [phantom] Done 4 steps in 6943ms
```

I expect the nodelist.length would be 3 not 0.

Comment: sorry, typing error. I mean  `line = nodelist[i];`

Answer (score 3):

PhantomJS' [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) function is the sandboxed page context. Everything that is passed, must be essentially stringified and parsed again.

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!**

This means that you can't get the elements out of the page context, but you can build a representation of them in the page context and pass it to the outside.

You probably want the `textContent` of those elements. You can use the CasperJS function [`getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) which provides the `text` property for each element. You can then filter the info only for this one property:

```
var texts = casper.getElementsInfo('tr.firstrow').map(function(tr){
    return tr.text;
});
```

If it is not the text you're after, you would have to find another representation or traverse the NodeList in the page context (inside `casper.evaluate()`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the `NodeList` (returned by `querySelectorAll`) to `Array`.

```
var nodelist=this.evaluate(function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr.firstrow'));
});
```